# No 'items' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '(_) -> (_) -> _'

Tags: rx-swift

In the following `strList` works fine, but when using `listOfRemoveEntity` I get a compiler error saying:

No 'items' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '(*) -> (*) -> _'

Only different is an array of `String` and an array of `RemoveEntity`. Do you know why?

```
public class RemoveEntity: Mappable {
    public var name: String?

    required public init?(map: Map){
    }

    public init() {
    }

    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var aTable: UITableView!
var listOfRemoveEntity = Variable<[RemoveEntity]>([])
var strList = Variable<[String]>([])

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func subscribeToStrList() {
    strList.value.append("111")
    strList.value.append("222")
    strList.value.append("333")

    listOfRemoveEntity.asObservable()
        .bindTo(
            aTable.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)
        ){  (row, item, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = item
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have: `cell.textLabel?.text = item` but item which is of type `RemoveEntity` isn't convertible to a String. Maybe you meant `item.name`?

Comment: That is just to easy :-) Thanks anyways. Sometimes one is just staring blind into something. Funny error message though.